# how to make a file name as a column in panda?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a CSV file which name is data.CSV and i want to make column from file name  for example data is column and value must be data as well  how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob('path to dir/*.csv')
df = None

for i, f in enumerate (files):
    if i == 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        df['fname'] = f
    else:
        tmp = read_csv(f)
        tmp['fname'] = f
        df = df.append(tmp)

df.head()
```

Comment: i got a error of invalid syntax can u help me solve this problem?

Comment: Sure, what the error says?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os.listdir()` in order to get the file name:

```
import os
file_name = os.listdir() # you need to use the path to the directory of the file

file_name_noext = file_name.replace(".csv", "") # in order to remove the .csv part
```

Now if you have a `DataFrame` called `data`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
data[file_name_noext] = file_name_noext # to update the dataframe
```